# How to Copy a File to a Directory Using Parts of the File Name as the File Path Using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to have Windows look at the name of a file, cut/paste that same file to a specific directory on a network. The name of the directory needs to be discovered from parsing out the file name. For example:

File Name: A1234567

Current File Path: C:\Documents\A1234567

Paste to File Path: E:\Shared\A123\A1234\A1234567

How do I do this for multiple files, somewhat of a loop command?

Comment: 1. This is too few information as you do not describe how the file name should be split. 2. This is not a free code writing service, so you need to show your own efforts! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick demo script, which should help guide you in how to parse your string:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "FileName=A1234567"
Set "CurrentFilePath=C:\Documents"
Set "PasteToPartPath=E:\Shared"

Set "FirstFour=%FileName:~0,4%"
Set "FirstFive=%FileName:~0,5%"

Set "PasteToFullPath=%PasteToPartPath%\%FirstFour%\%FirstFive%\%FileName%

Echo= %PasteToFullPath%

Pause
```